# reconfiguring key on mac

Tags: keyboard

I type a lot Unix commands and I need often "~" and "`" which in U.S. keyboards are on the key under the escape key.

I'm now using an Apple spanish keyboard set to U.S. layout, and this key 
is mapped to the characters "§" and "±"  instead. I can't find 
"~" and "`" anywhere, and I need them exactly at their usual place anyway.

Is there an easy way to remap the key that doesn't affect other users?
(they use the Spanish layout).  I'd rather not use apps like Karabiner
that ask to "control my computer" as I don't know what else it does, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Spanish keyboards have one key more than us keyboards, and the ~` key gets moved to the one just left of Z (marked <>) when you use a us layout.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'd like to remap this key and swap its function with the other one though.  Karabiner doesn't have this in the list of mapping. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: See the answer I posted below a few hours ago with the link

Answer (score 1):

I solve a similar problem using the free public domain utility [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). This allows for extremely extensive remapping of single or multiple key presses (including control keys) to any specifiable Unicode character, plus other operations. It is frequently updated, and photos has an older version for much older versions of OSX. You'll need to play a little bit with some examples to get what you want, but there's also pretty helpful documentation.

Comment: He does specifically say he would rather not use Karabiner.

Comment: Karabiner is open source. If @notuno is concerned about its access, they should check the source: [https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner).

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be only a couple minutes work to create a custom layout that does what you need with the graphic interface of Ukelele.

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

I made a quick one you can get at

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46870715/k/USMod.keylayout.zip

(but I can't test it because I don't have the right keyboard).

To install, put the .keylayout file in Library/Keyboard Layouts, logout/login, then go to system prefs/keyboard/input sources and use the plus and add buttons to add it (look in both English and Other categories), then select it from the input ("flag") menu in the menu bar.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Sorry I didn't notice your second post.